# Creating a code to read multiple sets of series data in an animated graph

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to produce an animated graph with over 40 columns of data. The graph is to move through each set of data along the columns. My code is attached below and I keep getting errors on line 5.

```
Sub Chart1()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Activate

Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Activate
Worksheets("TR01db.vel").ChartObjects("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(1000, 1))
Worksheets("TR01db.vel").ChartObjects("Chart 1").SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(1000, 2))
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For k = 0 To 100

  Worksheets("TR01db.vel").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(1000, 1))
  Worksheets("TR01db.vel").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("TR01db.vel").Range(Cells(4, 2 + k), Cells(1000, 2 + k))

Next k

BeforeExit:
Set rValues = Nothing
Set rCell = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Procedure Chart1"
Resume BeforeExit
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific error you get?

Comment: Run-Time error "438''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ChartObject is just a "container" for a Chart, so you need something more like:

```
Worksheets("TR01db.vel").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues 'etc
```

A lot of repetition could be avoided by using some variables:

```
Sub Chart1()

    Dim ws As WorkSheet, ser as Series
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TR01db.vel")

    With ws
        .Activate
        Set ser = .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        ser.XValues = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(1000, 1))
        ser.Values = .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(1000, 2))
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        For k = 0 To 100
            ser.Values = .Range(.Cells(4, 2 + k), .Cells(1000, 2 + k))
            DoEvents 'allow Excel to catch up...
        Next k
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @RachelSouthey if the answer was good for you, it is customary to accept it with the "tick" ...